Definition of semi-metric for empirical process theory
In the following lecture notes on empirical processes (https://www.stat.columbia.edu/~bodhi/Talks/Emp-Proc-Lecture-Notes.pdf) a semi-metric space $(\Theta, d)$ is defined in the following way: for any $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3 \in \Theta$ we have $d(\theta_1, \theta_2) = 0 \implies \theta_1 = \theta_2;$ (ii) $ d(\theta_1, \theta_2) = d(\theta_2, \theta_1)$; and (iii) $d(\theta_1, \theta_3) \leq d(\theta_1, \theta_2) + d(\theta_2, \theta_3)$. See footnote 24 on page 17.
However, I am a bit confused about the first point. In the book 'Asymptotic Statistics' by Van der Vaart, a metric is defined in the standard way. It is then mentioned that the property
$$
d(\theta_1, \theta_2) = 0 \iff \theta_1 = \theta_2
$$
does not need to hold for a semi-metric. So in Van der Vaart, we can have that any of the  two implications does not hold. On the other side, the lecture notes by Sen require that the implications from left to right still holds. This means that for these notes, a semi-metric is a metric which does not need to satisfy $\theta_1 = \theta_2 \implies d(\theta_1, \theta_2) = 0$.
I am in doubt whether the definition in Sen could be a typo. For me, it makes more sense that we want to allow for multiple elements in a space that have distance zero. However, Sen only allows for elements which have non-zero distance to themselves. If this is not a typo, what would be the benefit of allowing elements to have non-zero distance to themselves? In particular, what would be the benefit of allowing this for studying empirical processes?
